# Pass statement with function in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, attributes, addeventlistener

Before you read: Yes this is a common question. However none of them solved my problem, and also none/almost none used a for-loop, which causes problems for me.

My code creates 5 DIVs which all get their own ID, and should get their own unique onClick listener. But adding eventListener with an argument does not work like I want it to.

In order to get the correct output when pressing the onClick element, I need to pass an argument with the function that is run onClick. Take a look at the code.

I saw a lot of other people having this problem but none of them solved this. I have tried this (anonymous function):

```
div.addEventListener("click", function() {
        calc(i);
    }, false);
```

However on all the event listeners I get an argument with value 6, meaning that I don't get individual onClicks for the DIVs (my goal). All the onClick elements return "six" in the console.

```
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "i"+i);
    div.setAttribute("class", "test-item");
    div.innerHTML = i;
    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
        calc(i);
    }, false);
    document.querySelector(".testContainer").appendChild(div);
}

function calc(num) {
    switch (num) {
        case 1:
        console.log("one");
            break;
        case 2:
        console.log("two");
            break;
        case 3:
        console.log("three");
            break;
        case 4:
        console.log("four");
            break;
        case 5:
        console.log("five");
            break;
        case 6:
        console.log("six");
            break;
        default:
        console.log("Error");
        break;
    }
  }
```

Here:
https://jsfiddle.net/nbps7mdr/3/

What I expect:

When I click the div with number 1, I get "one" in console.
I do not expect to get any "six" at all, because the max number should be 5. There is something wrong meaning that 6 is sent with i.

Comment: This has to do with the scope of your variable `i`. Because the for loop is complete before you click any of the buttons, `i` will be 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your for loop to use a `let`. That way it will be block scoped instead of scoped to the enclosing function.

```
for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "i"+i);
    div.setAttribute("class", "test-item");
    div.innerHTML = i;
    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
        calc(i);
    }, false);
    document.querySelector(".testContainer").appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: That worked! What do you mean  with the block being scoped and "enclosing function" though?

Comment: @Marcus I'd encourage you to take a look at the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). Basically `i` will be scoped to the for loop, instead of globally. Variable scoping in JavaScript is a massive topic, so I'd encourage you to do some research on it :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a tweak here, not sure if this will work for you. Added the event param and ref the text. Then parseInt in the func.

```js
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "i"+i);
    div.setAttribute("class", "test-item");
    div.innerHTML = i;
    div.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        calc(event.target.innerText);
    }, false);
    document.querySelector(".testContainer").appendChild(div);
}

function calc(num) {
    num=parseInt(num);
    switch (num) {
        case 1:
        console.log("one");
            break;
        case 2:
        console.log("two");
            break;
        case 3:
        console.log("three");
            break;
        case 4:
        console.log("four");
            break;
        case 5:
        console.log("five");
            break;
        case 6:
        console.log("six");
            break;
        default:
        console.log("Error");
        break;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="testContainer"></div>
```

Another option, work with scope. Declare a local variable in the eventListener. Set it to i (note: i is a value type so this works):

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "i"+i);
    div.setAttribute("class", "test-item");
    div.innerHTML = i;
    div.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let n = i;
        calc(n);
    }, false);
    document.querySelector(".testContainer").appendChild(div);
}

function calc(num) {
    switch (num) {
        case 1:
        console.log("one");
            break;
        case 2:
        console.log("two");
            break;
        case 3:
        console.log("three");
            break;
        case 4:
        console.log("four");
            break;
        case 5:
        console.log("five");
            break;
        case 6:
        console.log("six");
            break;
        default:
        console.log("Error");
        break;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="testContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution. And look at Charlie Fish's comment on scope

```js
const root = document.querySelector('#root');

function init() {
    for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        const div = createDiv(i);

        div.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);

        root.appendChild(div);
    }
}

function createDiv(i) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');

    div.id = i;
    div.className = 'test-item';
    div.textContent = i;

    return div;
}

function handleClick(event) {
    const id = parseInt(event.target.id, 10);

    switch(id) {
        case 1:
            console.log('one');
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log('two');
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log('three');
            break;
        case 4:
            console.log('four');
            break;
        case 5:
            console.log('five');
            break;
        case 6:
            console.log('six');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Error');
    }
}

init();
```

```css
.test-item {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```